# $4x + 6y =36$ represents a straight line graph. Find $x$ when $y=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

$4x + 6y =36$ represents a straight line graph. Find

i) $x$ when $y=0$

ii) $y$ when $x=0$

---

I don't know how to start this. I was thinking of

$6y= 4x -36$ or $y=(m)(x)=0$

but it's all confusing and I don't know where to put the numbers

Comment: What's confusion in it? x=9 at y=0 and y=6 at x=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following equation of the straight line: $$4x+6y=36$$ 
1. Setting $y=0$, we get $$4x+6(0)=36\iff x=\frac{36}{4}=9$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{x=9}}$$

2. Setting $x=0$, we get $$4(0)+6y=36\iff y=\frac{36}{6}=6$$
   $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{y=6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Plug in $y=0$:

$$4x+6(0)=36$$

This is the same as

$$4x=36$$

Then divide by $4$

$$x=9$$

Do the same for the other.

Answer (score 1):

$4x+6y=36$

Put  in this equation $x=0$ we get $6y=36 $

dividing both  sides by $6$ we get $y=6$.

Now put $y=0$ in equation $4x+6y=36$

we get $4x=36$

dividing both sides by $4$  we  get $x=9$.

Answer (score 1):

$4x+6y=36$

Put $x=0$,$4\times 0+6y=36\Rightarrow 6y=36\Rightarrow y=6$

Put $y=0$,$4x+6\times 0=36\Rightarrow 4x=36\Rightarrow x=9$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by simple substitution.

Given
$$ 4x + 6y =36 ,$$

1. You need to find $x $ when $y=0$. 
   Substituting $y=0$ into original equation, we get
   $$4x + 6 \!\cdot\!0  = 36 
   \implies 4x = 36 \implies x = 9,$$
   so that for $y=0$ the answer is $x=9$.
2. Similarly, substituting $x = 0$ into $4x + 6y =36$, we get 
   $$
   4\! \cdot \! 0 + 6y =36 \implies 6 y = 36 \implies y = 6,
   $$
   so that for $x=0$ the answer is $y=6$.